# Save a new .tsv file for each record in a .csv file in Python

Tags: python, pandas

this is my first question, waiting to answer to many others of yours. What I wanna do is create a lot of new .tsv files, one for each record (row) of a big .csv file. What I've done since now is basically create a new .txt file that has all the data of the .csv file separated by a tab instead of a comma. This is what i've done:

```
with open('mycsv.csv','r', encoding="utf-8") as csvin, open('out.txt', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as tsvout:
    csvin = csv.reader(csvin)
    tsvout = csv.writer(tsvout, delimiter='\t')

    for row in csvin:
        tsvout.writerow(row)
```

Thank you for your help.

Edit: I forgot! I also wanna name the output tsv files as doc_i.tsv where i is the row number of each record in the .csv file.

Comment: If you want to `create a lot of new .tsv files, one for each record (row) of a big .csv file` you need to have two separate with-blocks instead of one with two file creations, with the second one being within the for-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is one way of doing it, using [np.array_split](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('big_file.csv')
tsvs = np.array_split(df, df.shape[0])

for i, tsv in enumerate(tsvs):
    tsv.to_csv('{}.tsv'.format(i), sep='\t', index=False, header=False)
```

Please take note that this will create files named `0.tsv`, `1.tsv`... And you can change that in `to_csv` call.

Comment: Thanks. I did this way and it actually creates a lot of .tsv files each of which is a row of the dataframe. But in each .tsv file i get also all the labels of the dataframe.
And what this solution is also doing is also crea creating infinite files with onlt the labels of the .csv file. In each .tsv file i just need one row with the data instead of two rows (labels and data). 
I had to stop running the command manually.

Comment: @PaoloG. I've added the `header=False` which excludes labels.

Comment: Thanks, but it continues iterating infinetly, creating empty .tsv files after creating the ones that i actually need. Had to stop it manually again.

Comment: @PaoloG. Sorry for that, I forgot to change `size` to `shape[0]`, now it will work as expected.

Comment: Thank you!! Last thing: what if i don't wanto to include in each .tsv file the index of each row? I've tried to add also index_label=False but it didn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Inside each of my output .tsv files the row starts with a number: 1 for the first file, 2 for the second, exc...

Comment: @PaoloG That could only mean that you have some custom index column (pandas index starts with 0) that produces such result. Try excluding it using `df.drop('column_name', axis=1, inplace=True)` before splitting the file.

Comment: Thank you! There was un unlabeled column in the csv file that i didn't see.